# understanding a question that asks for probability of flips of coins

Tags: probability

> Independent flips of a coin that lands on heads with probability $p$
> are made. What is the probability that string THHH occurs before the
> string $HHHH$?

#### Attempt

I have a little trouble understanding this problem. I realize we can use conditional probability

$$ P(HHHH \mid THHH ) = \frac{P(HHHH \cap THHH) }{P(THHH)} $$

How to understand the event $HHHH \cap THHH$? this is basically saying that we obtain string HHHH and THHH which cannot happen at the same time. Is the probability im trying to find correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of THHH or HHHH must occur first - it is impossible for neither to ever occur.

Complementary counting gives us

$$P\,\big(\text{THHH occurs before HHHH}\big) \,\,= \,\,1-P\,\big(\text{HHHH occurs before THHH}\big)$$

In order for HHHH to occur before THHH, the first four flips must all be H (think about why this must be the case). Given that, we can rewrite

$$
\begin{align*}
P\,\big(\text{THHH occurs before HHHH}\big) \,\,&= \,\,1-P\,\big(\text{first four flips are all heads}\big)\\\\
&= \,\,1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\\\\
&= \,\,1 - \frac{1}{16}\\\\
&= \,\,\boxed{\,\frac{15}{16}\,\,}
\end{align*}
$$

---

If the coin is weighted with probability of heads $p\neq 1/2$, simply substitue $p$ for $1/2$ in the above calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that the sequence $HHHH$ can only precede the sequence $THHH$ if the first four flips are heads.  The probability that the first four flips are heads is $p^4$.  Therefore, the probability that the sequence $THHH$ occurs before the sequence $HHHH$ is $1 - p^4$.